# Android studio not detecting devices

Tags: applications, android-studio

I am currently using windows 10 enterprise and my android studio does not detect devices despite me installing drive pack 17 and also adb fastboot drivers all phones are detected by the machine but android studio does not detect the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Enable USB debugging while you have plugged the phone in on android studio. Then a pop-up should appear, allow permission for your pc to do usb debugging. This might be the case since the phone is being detected by the device, usb debugging is found in `Settings > Developer tools`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android Device Manager]

Check Whether the program is running locally through your Android Virtual Device Manager

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the following:

1.The connection is set to "allow file transfer " and not "charge only mode".
2.Ensure having developer privileges in your device and also enabling USB debugging.